# Trouble refreshing listview after deleting item in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

I have a problem refreshing the cardviews in a listview after deleting or editing one cardview, I have tried with the `.notifyDataSetChanged()` but didn't work. I'm really new in Android Studio.

Here is my code:

RegistroActivity

```
public class RegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

private List<Registro> items = new ArrayList<>();
private RegistroAdapter registroAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);



    RegistroModel registroModel = new RegistroModel();
    Cursor query = registroModel.showReg(HomeActivity.database);

    if (query.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Registro expense = new Registro(query.getInt(0), query.getString(1), query.getFloat(2), query.getFloat(3), query.getString(4), query.getString(5) );
            items.add(expense);
        } while (query.moveToNext());
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RegistroAdapter(items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I fill the data from a model with a simple select * from, and send the data to the adapter. Here is my adapter:

```
public class RegistroAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegistroAdapter.RegistroViewHolder> {
private List<Registro> items;

public static class RegistroViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView color;
    public TextView descr;
    public TextView precio;
    public TextView cantidad;
    public ImageButton delete_expense;
    public ImageButton edit_expense;

    public Context cont;

    public RegistroViewHolder(View v, Context context) {
        super(v);
        color = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_image);

        descr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        precio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.precio);
        cantidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);

        delete_expense = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        edit_expense = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        cont = context;

    }
}
public RegistroAdapter(List<Registro> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public RegistroViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.registro_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new RegistroViewHolder(v, viewGroup.getContext());
}
//
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RegistroViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    String gramos = viewHolder.cont.getResources().getString(R.string.gramos);
    String fecha = viewHolder.cont.getResources().getString(R.string.fecha);
    String desc = viewHolder.cont.getResources().getString(R.string.tvDesc);

    viewHolder.color.setImageResource(R.color.fondoCard);

    viewHolder.descr.setText(fecha + " " + items.get(i).getDate() + "\n" + "\n" + " " + items.get(i).getDesc());
    viewHolder.precio.setText(items.get(i).getPrice().toString() + " " + items.get(i).getMoneda() );
    viewHolder.cantidad.setText(items.get(i).getAmount().toString() + " " + gramos  );


    viewHolder.edit_expense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditRegistroActivity.class);
            int pos = items.get(i).getId();
            intent.putExtra("position", pos);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.delete_expense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            int pos = items.get(i).getId();
            try{
                SQLiteDatabase conn = HomeActivity.database.getWritableDatabase();
                int n = conn.delete("registro","id="+pos, null);
                if (n == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getString(R.string.mensajeEliminarexito), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),v.getContext().getString(R.string.mensajeErrorEliminar) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error. ID=" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

I set the data within the elements in the card-view, this card-view has two Image-buttons to delete and edit each item in the card-view. I set the onClickListener for them. It edits and deletes completely fine but it doesn't refresh the information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are making any changes on SQLite db and not in the adapter's `items` List. Adapter works only with the dataset you have passed to it when initializing it in your `RegistroActivity`. Therefore, when you want to change something you need to change SQLite to store modification permanently and refresh the dataset in adapters to allow user see the changes.

In your case, try adding three lines of code that are given below:

```
viewHolder.delete_expense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        int pos = items.get(i).getId();
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase conn = HomeActivity.database.getWritableDatabase();
            int n = conn.delete("registro","id="+pos, null);

            items.remove(i);
            notifyItemRemoved(i);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(i, item.size());

            if (n == 1){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getString(R.string.mensajeEliminarexito), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),v.getContext().getString(R.string.mensajeErrorEliminar) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error. ID=" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your item from adapter before notifying, like this

```
items.remove(i);
```

When you remove item from db it will not update you list, because your adapter holds data from passed before list.